# Ways to choose $6$ numbers from $\{1, \dots, 20\}$ so that at least four are odd

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways are there to choose $6$ numbers from the set $\{1, \dots, 20\}$ so that at least four of them are odd?

I came up with two different answers to this question, and I can't see why either one of them is wrong. I'd like to know which one is incorrect (assuming one of them is actually correct).

Solution 1: There are three types of sets of $6$ numbers such that four of them are odd. We could have $4$ odd and $2$ even, $5$ odd and $1$ even, or all $6$ odd. From this, we get the following solution: $${10 \choose 4}\cdot{10 \choose 2} + {10 \choose 5}\cdot{10 \choose 1} + {10 \choose 6} = 12180.$$

Solution 2: At least $4$ of the numbers need to be odd, so let's pick those first, and then we can pick any $2$ from the remaining $16.$ This gives us the following solution: $${10 \choose 4}\cdot{16 \choose 2} = 25200.$$

Something feels off about the second solution, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Any help?

Comment: The second solution has some double counting e.g. $\{1, 3, 5, 7\}$ then $\{15, 17\}$  is the same as $\{1, 3, 5, 15\}$ and then $\{7, 17\}$

Comment: Are you looking for "ordered" ways, since permutations is a tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted, your second method double-counts some combinations.

Let me suggest a different way to approach the problem using symmetry.  There are $\binom {20}{6}=38,760$ total possible combinations with no constraints.  There are $\binom {10}{3} \binom {10}{3}=14,400$ possible combinations with exactly $3$ odd numbers and $3$ even numbers.

Of the remaining combinations, exactly half have at least $4$ odd numbers.  Therefore, the answer is $\frac 12 \left ( \binom {20}{6} - \binom {10}{3} \binom {10}{3} \right )=12,180$.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is correct, assuming you want the unordered ways, and there is no replacement of the elements.